# Why are all product options selected on the update page?

Tags: magento2, frontend, bundled-product

Before I add a bundle product to the cart, I'll uncheck one product option from bundle selected options (attach)

[image: a]

but when I want to edit this product, all parameters are selected by default in the update page (attach)

[image]

Is this ok?